# Javascript - Fazer <article> aparecer ao clicar em um <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma pequena dúvida em meu projeto que estou desenvolvendo.

Preciso fazer com que determinado `<article>` apareça ao ser clicado um determinado `<li>`.

> Exemplo `<li>`'s

```
<li id="menu-CARD">USAR CARD</li>

<li id="menu-SLIP">USAR SLIP</li>
```

> Exemplo `<article>`'s

```
<article id="CARD">CONTEÚDO CARD</article>

<article id="SLIP">CONTEÚDO SLIP</article>
```

---

**Preciso de duas coisas.**

- 1° Ao clicar em uma das `<li>`, seja adicionada a class
  "**selected**" à `<li>` clicada. (`class="selected"`)
- 2° Ao clicar em uma `<li>`, será exibido o `<article>` que
  é referido à essa `<li>` que foi clicada.

---

Exemplo: ao clicar na `<li>` **"USAR SLIP"**:

```
<li id="menu-SLIP">USAR SLIP</li>
```

Será adicionado um **style="display:block"** ao `<article>` de id **"SLIP"**:

```
<article id="SLIP">CONTEÚDO SLIP</article>
```

---

Ficando assim:

```
<article id="SLIP" style="display:block">CONTEÚDO SLIP</article>
```

---

Obsevação:

Sua função será semelhante à uma aba.

Quando clicar em USAR CARD, exibirá o `<article>` de id **"CARD"**.

Quando clicar em USAR SLIP, exibirá o `<article>` de id **"SLIP"**.

Ou seja, enquanto um receber **display:block**, o outro recebe **display:none**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse código faz o básico que você precisa, mas dê uma lida sobre seletores do jQuery, principalmente como selecionar elementos por atributos.

```
var scrollDuration = 800; // 1000ms = 1 segundo

//ao clicar em uma <li>
$('li').click(function(){

  //pegamos a id do elemento clicado,
  //dividimos o nome da id no ponto "menu-" e
  // pegamos o lado da direita, de índice 1  

  var target = $(this).attr('id').split('menu-')[1];

  //remove classe do 'selected' do elemento com ela
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

  //adiciona classe no 'selected' no elemento clicado
  $(this).addClass('selected');  

  //escondemos o <article> com classe 'visible'  
  $('article.visible')
    .css('display','none')
    .removeClass('visible');

  //podemos concatenar a var target com '#', o que forma
  //uma query para o jquery: '#SLIP' ou '#CARD'
  $('#'+target)
    .css('display','block')
    .addClass('visible');

  //agora que o elemento está visível, vamos dar scroll até ele
  //http://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/2467235      
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( '#'+target ).offset().top
  }, scrollDuration);

});
```

Uma outra alternativa interessante pode ser adicionar/remover classes que escondem/mostram os elementos.
No exemplo uso uma classe chamada "visible" para marcar o article atual. Se no seu css você colocar

```
.article{ /* todos os article's começam escondidos */
  display:none;
}
article.visible{ /* mostra um article que tenha a class visible */
  display:block;
}
```

Não vai ser necessário utilizar a linhas de JS com `.css('display','none')`

Comment: Amigo, testei seu código. Tem dois problemas, primeiro, ele dá o "display:none" em todos os articles da página (é possível fazer somentes em articles com determinada class? tipo: `<article class="este-pode"`) ?. Segundo, ele não remove a class "selected". O correto é enquanto uma li ficar com "selected" a outra fica sem o "selected".

Comment: Amigo, eu resolvi a parte que eu escolho quais `<articles>` vão receber o `display:none`, mudei para `$('.essesim').css('display','none');`... Agora falta só fazer com que apenas 1 `<li>` fique com a `class=selected`.

Comment: Ajustei esta questão na resposta, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Ficou perfeito! Parabéns pelo seu conhecimento e por ajudar as pessoas com ele! Muito obrigado. Só tenho uma dúvida adicional :3, é possível fazer com que quando a pessoa clicar na li, a tela desça para o início do `<li>`? Muito bomm!

Comment: Tipo aquele scroll suave, que faz a dela descer pra `<li>` clicada.

Comment: O scroll pode ser implementado com esse snippet aqui, vou incluir na resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/2467235

Comment: PERFEITO!!! Você é um gênio!

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro de tudo, seus elementos `<li>` precisam ter uma **class**. Segundo, não precisa do atributo `ID`. Dentro do `<li>` coloque um `<a>` com um **HREF** apontando para o `ID` o `<article>`

Atribua uma propriedade no CSS para que o primeiro  apareça como default e no primeiro `<li>` no **HTML** como `selected`.

```js
$('.showArticle > a').on('click', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('href'); // Pega o HREF do A que é o ID do Article
   var articles = $('article');

   $('.showArticle').removeClass('selected'); // Remove a classe selected dos LIS
   $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); // Aplica a classe selected ao LI selecionado 

   articles.css('display', 'none'); // Esconde todos os Articles
   $(id).css('display', 'block'); // Mostra apenas o selecionado.
});
```

```css
article{
    display: none;
}

section article:first-child{
    display: block; /* ou block */
}

ul li a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul li.selected a{
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="showArticle selected"><a href="#card">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="showArticle"><a href="#slip">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="showArticle"><a href="#folk">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<section>
  <article id="card">Article 1</article>
  <article id="slip">Article 2</article>
  <article id="folk">Article 3</article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

A questão se parece mais com um pedido, por isso vou responder só com um código de exemplo :p

```
var defaultArticle
var articles$ = {}

articles$[defaultArticle = "CARD"] = $("#CARD")
articles$.SLIP = $("#SLIP")

var selectArticle = identifier => {
  for (var i in articles) {
    var method = i === identifier ?
                 "show" : "hide"
    articles$[i][method]()
  }
}

var $lis;

var selectLi = identifier => {
  $lis.each(function(i) {
    var method = i === identifier ?
                 "addClass" : "removeClass"
    this[method]("selected")
  })
}

$lis.click(function() {
  var articleId = this.id.split('-')[1]
  selectArticle(articleId)
  selectLi(this.id)
})

/* Visualiza o article padrão */
selectArticle(defaultArticle)

/* e seleciona o li padrão (dá para melhorar essa seleção) */
selectLi($lis[0].id)
```